# MaskedTextBox is cleared when losing focus

Tags: c#, windows

I have `MaskedTextBox` to enter a date with masked property set to "99/99/9999". When I run the application and enter a date in the MaskedTextBox, the value vanishes after losing focus. How can I solve this?

Comment: Is this in C#? Do you have an `OnTextChanged` handler or focus lost or some other processing for this text box? We will need to see some code  in order to help you. As it stands right now your question is unanswerable.

Comment: @pstrjds yes it is c# applicaton. It does not have ontextchanged event or focuslost event.

Answer (score 0):

This Link may help you to find a solution:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/maskedtextbox-in-C-Sharp/

Do you have the properties of MaskTxtbox set as below images

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: no this link  not solution to  my problem. When I enter date in maskedtextbox and press tab then it get vanishes. Cant see and cant enter into database. Please help it's very tedy and allready takes my 2  days for this error

Comment: just see my property windows in my edited answer..
Its working for me

Comment: This means its a normal textbox without mask property. I set masked property to "99/99/9999". Other than this all propertis are same like your's But not working

Comment: Its working fine for me Nilesh...
Can you please let me know why you use this masked textbox?

Comment: Please tell me how I can paste my form design to this forum. So that it;s more clear to you that what I want to say

Comment: In your question area, you can find a icon with picture, you can upload image through it.

Comment: Sorry I can't paste image since I am new here. It tell me to earn 10 reputation to post images. Do you have other way so I can communicate with you? Thnks

Comment: its ok...Are you going to use this date(you entered in mask text box) in storing in database.

Comment: yes. It will be store in sql server database. But when press tab date get vanishes and database shows null value in sql server

Comment: It stores date in the database right...Then use DateTimePicker instead of that.

Comment: yes. It will be store in sql server database. But when press tab date get vanishes and database shows null value in sql server

Comment: DataTimePicker also results in same issue uh?

Comment: no I tried datetimepicker allready. It give problem with databinding source,binding navigator, and datagridview that I am using in my form. It shows null value when we select default date showing by datetimepicker.

Comment: It's not get vanishes the selected date but while binding to binding source and gridview thenthere is problem.